# Salesforce Tab + Visualforce community open in lightning mode....for community users

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have create a community with template visualforce page + Tabs. When i login to community as admin i can see the classic tab view of community, but when i login as portal user i get redirected to lightning view...

I created a portal user for testing and logged into community using username and password...still the community users view is lightning.

How could this be...Also anyone knows how to fix this.
Thanks